# Is this the right way to organize an equal statement?

Tags: php, hyperlink, equals

Is this the right format? When i try to use it it gives me a blank page with no error msg.

```
$type = $row['page_type'];

$art = "Article";
$vid = "Video";
$pho = "Photo";
$link = "Link";

if ( $type === $art ) {
  $page = "art.php";
} elseIF ($type === $vid) {
  $page = "vid.php";
} elseIF ($type === $pho) {
  $page = "photo.php";
} else { 
  } elseIF ($type === $link) {
    $page = "link.php";
  } else { 
    echo("Error");
  }
```

Comment: @mellamokb: I'm not sure that "fixing code" in an edit is a good idea when the asker is complaining that their code isn't working. :)

Comment: @Andrzej: Agreed.  Reverted back :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra `}else{`

```
if ( $type === $art ) {
      $page = "art.php";
}elseif($type === $vid) {
      $page = "vid.php";
}elseif($type === $pho) {
      $page = "photo.php";
// This should not be here --> }else{ 
}elseif($type === $link) {
      $page = "link.php";
}else{ 
      echo("Error");
}
```

EDIT:

You could also use a hash for this:

```
$h = array("Article"=>"article.php", "Video"=>"vid.php", ...);
if(array_key_exists($type, $h)){
    $page = $h[$type];
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: Also set `display_errors=1` and `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` in your development machine. You would have found the parse error more easily